# Laravel 5 & Mamp - stores weird path when uploading a file

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */


public function store(AdminProgramRequest $request)
{
    $request = $this->move_image_file($request, 'thumbnail');
    $request = $this->move_image_file($request, 'korean_brochure');
    $request = $this->move_image_file($request, 'english_brochure');
    $request = $this->move_image_file($request, 'chinese_brochure');

    Program::create($request->all());

    return redirect('dashboard/program_category/'.$request->program_category_id.'/edit');
}



private function move_image_file($request, $input_name)
{
    if($request->hasFile($input_name)){
        $filename = $request->file($input_name)->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file($input_name)->move(
            base_path() . '/public/pdf/program_category/' . $request->program_category_id . '/' , $filename
        );    
        $request->merge([

            // I think this is where
            // /private/var/folders/_l/9jdb6p2s3ms4vh8jv0mp_43w0000gn/T/phphi95xw 
            // stuff gets stored in $request even if
            // $filename has the uploaded filename for sure.
            $input_name => $filename

            // This hardcode also works in the same way and stores weird path in db... WHY!?
            // $input_name => 'whats_going_on.jpg'  
        ]);
    }
    return $request;
}
```

This is driving me nuts. I'm pretty sure that $filename has the filename of the uploaded file.

1. I've double checked if $filename has a correct value. Yes.
2. I've hardcoded and given a randome filename to $filname. Still doesn't work but stores the weird path thing.
3. I've tested if files are being uploaded correctly. and Yes.
4. I've checked view files. Since #3 is working, of course Yes.

Now, I'm suspecting MAMP.

Has anyone experienced the same issue with Laravel5 and Mamp on OSX?